# Conditional rendering: comparing the result of async function in v-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, axios

I have a `Vue` component for a sidebar with a template defined as:

```
Vue.component('navigation',{
  template:`
    <ul class="nav">
      <li v-if="checkIfUserIsAdmin() == true" id="adminMenu"></li>
      <li id="userMenu"></li>
  `,
  methods: {
    checkIfUserIsAdmin() {
      var result = false;
      axiosInstance.get("/Profile/GetUserInfo").then(userInfo => {
        result = userInfo.data.u.isAdmin;
      })
      .catch(userError => {
        swal({
          title: "Operational Platform",
          text: "Unable to retrieve user info"
        });
        result = false;
      });
      return result;
    }
  }
});
```

Some code was removed for brevity.
When I visit the `/Profile/GetUserInfo` I get a JSON in return that's properly returning me `true` but the adminMenu is not displaying and I'm wondering why. It seems that the `v-if` is the place that I've messed up. I've tried also changing the adminMenu to have `v-if="checkIfUserIsAdmin() == 'true'"` but it still didn't work.

Comment: uses watch/data property instead of `v-if="async function"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the method's result.

First you need to run the `checkIfUserIsAdmin` method when the component is mounted.
In `checkIfUserIsAdmin` method you need to store the result of the query in `adminMenuDisplay` variable and then you can watch this variable in `v-if`.

```
Vue.component('navigation',{
  template:`
    <ul class="nav">
      <li v-if="adminMenuDisplay" id="adminMenu"></li>
      <li id="userMenu"></li>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      adminMenuDisplay: false
    };
  }
  methods: {
    checkIfUserIsAdmin() {
      var result = false;
      axiosInstance.get("/Profile/GetUserInfo").then(userInfo => {
        this.adminMenuDisplay = userInfo.data.u.isAdmin;
      })
      .catch(userError => {
        swal({
          title: "Operational Platform",
          text: "Unable to retrieve user info"
        });
        this.adminMenuDisplay = false;
      });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.checkIfUserIsAdmin();
  }
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I have now a better understanding of component lifecycle thanks to that.